# Login through Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, authentication

I try to create login method and in this login method I try to call stored procedure like this

**UPDATED CODE**

When I try this and click on button this show something like this ..

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

Button code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
}

public bool  loginmethod(string UserName,string Password)
{
       TrackDataEntities1 td = new TrackDataEntities1();
       // splogin_Result sp=td.splogin(UserName,Password);
       splogin1_Result sp = td.splogin1(UserName, Password).FirstOrDefault();

       if(sp.Password == txt_pwd.Text)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
}
```

When I add the stored procedure in model I set return type complex type for splogin and complex name is splogin1_Result and Function Import name is splogin1

Now `splogin1_Result`

```
public partial class splogin1_Result : ComplexObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new splogin1_Result object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">Initial value of the UserName property.</param>
    /// <param name="password">Initial value of the Password property.</param>
    public static splogin1_Result Createsplogin1_Result(global::System.String userName, global::System.String password)
    {
        splogin1_Result splogin1_Result = new splogin1_Result();
        splogin1_Result.UserName = userName;
        splogin1_Result.Password = password;
        return splogin1_Result;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Simple Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserName;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUserNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("UserName");
            _UserName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false, "UserName");
            ReportPropertyChanged("UserName");
            OnUserNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _UserName;
    partial void OnUserNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnUserNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _Password;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPasswordChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Password");
            _Password = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false, "Password");
            ReportPropertyChanged("Password");
            OnPasswordChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Password;
    partial void OnPasswordChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPasswordChanged();

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The `splogin()` method returns an `ObjectResult<splogin_Result>` (*many* of `splogin_Result`) while the code that is invoking the method expects a single `splogin_Result` in return. Perhaps you need `td.splogin(UserName,Password).SingleOrDefault()` or change your method to return a single `splogin_Result` instead of `ObjectResult<splogin_Result>`

Comment: please check update

Comment: Now it's your `loginmethod()` that is returning the wrong type. You defined it as returning `bool` while you actually `return sp`. Perhaps `return sp != null` is what you need?

Comment: can i change this bool to any other type ie. public void?

Comment: If the intention of the `loginmethod()` is to check whether a certain username and password combination yields a valid and authenticated user in the system, I assume `bool` is indeed what you want (`true` = correct login details, `false` = invalid login).

Comment: yes i want to validate username and password...

Comment: NOW PLEASE CHECK UPDATE

Comment: ok now i solved this .

Answer (score 0):

I try this and this work for me

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
            }
            catch( Exception )
            {
                Label1.Text = ("Wrong info");
            }


        }
        public bool  loginmethod(string UserName,string Password)
        {
            T1 td = new T1();

         splogin1_Result sp = td.splogin1(UserName, Password).FirstOrDefault();
           if(sp.Password==txt_pwd.Text)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }

        }
```